# VS2012 Large String Array Declaration crashes Visual Studio

Tags: arrays, string, visual-studio-2012, crash

I have been moving a solution from VS2010 to VS2012 and came across a problem relating to the declaration of a large public shared 1-d string array. ie. something like:

Public Shared words() As String = { "...", "...",,, "...", "...}

I have 13331 separate string elements in this array.  I am coding in VB.

It seems that above a certain string count Visual Studio 2012 crashes.  This appears to be a characteristic of VS2012 as both VS2010 and in fact VS2008 where both fine with this bit of code.

Has anyone seen this type of behaviour before?  Is there a way of setting up a solution/project so that arrays are not limited in this way?

Comment: I tried to repro this on VS2013 but my laptop caught fire before it got close to crashing VS.  I'd say that bug was fixed.

Comment: One other point - it appears that the maximum number of elementsthat can be decalred without crashing the VS2012 platform is around 5245. It is not easy to specify a distinct limit, as it appears to vary on the basis of the number of elementd added at a single time - the 5245 limit was approached a single elemetn at a time as adding five elements at 5240 crashed it also, whilst gradually getting to 5245 did not.

Comment: In VS2013, I'm encountering a similar bug on the C# side when declaring new byte[] { ...a few thousand entries... }; VS simply crashes outright with a bad memory reference.  I don't think they fixed that issue as well as one might hope.